# How to use nn.conv2d to do the same function as nn.conv1d?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytorch, conv-neural-network

I'm working on deploying python CNNs on FPGAs, and i'm facing an issue.

I have a 1d CNN which uses `torch.conv1d` layer function, and it's not supported by the software I'm using :`vitis-ai 1.3`.

I'm figuring out if there is some way to use `nn.conv2d` instead to do the same job as `nn.conv1d` ?

for example :

```
Conv1d(1, 32, 3, bias = True) => Conv2d(...
```

Is there a way to do that ? (without loosing too much performance ?)

Thank you.

Comment: In what sense are `nn.Conv2d` supported but `nn.Conv1d` are not?

Answer (score 0):

Given 1d input, a 2d convolution of kernel-size `(n,1)` is equivalent to a 1d convolution of kernel-size `(n,)`:

```py
nn.Conv1d(in_channels, out_channels, n)

# for 1d input, is equivalent to:
nn.Conv2d(in_channels, out_channels, (n,1))
```

---

Note you will have to `unsqueeze(-1)` the input to get it of the correct shape for a 2d convolution, but you can return the output to the original shape by applying `squeeze(-1)`:

```py
F.conv1d(inputs, filters)

# is equivalent to:
F.conv2d(inputs.unsqueeze(-1), filters.unsqueeze(-1)).squeeze(-1)
```